# Android - Pagination with Retrofit

Tags: android, pagination, retrofit

With Retrofit, what is the best way of loading 'more' data in a paginated REST response?

#### Background

I'm migrating to Retrofit from AsyncTasks + Loaders. Unlike the situation of OP in this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890133/how-to-handle-pagination-in-retrofit), I would like to have Retrofit fetch data only on request as opposed to downloading all items at once. Currently, it's easy to do this when the user scrolls to the end of the current list view page by invoking `LoaderManager.restartLoader()`.

A sample response of the API our client consumes:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "nid": 4382,
      "comment_text": "some user comment", ...
    }, ...
  ],
  "paging": {
    "nextPage": "http://api.domain.net/v2/comments?page=1&pageSize=20&requestLandmark=M4ewMnwxDUsdadf0NTIwfDU2OA==%3D%3D",
    "itemsTotal": 5164,
    "page": 0,
    "pagerMax": 218,
    "requestLandmark": "M4ewMnwxDUsdadf0NTIwfDU2OA=="
  }
}
```

I know that we can provide the 'page' param to our APIService like this:

```
public interface APIService {
  @GET("/comments/{page}") //
  List<Comment> getComments(@Path("page") int page);
}
```

However, the challenge is that we have many other endpoints that get us different lists of data besides comments (user stories, likes, trending, etc), and we wouldn't like to write a `loadMore()` method for each endpoint we have to fetch additional pages for if there's a better alternative. In other words, it would be clumsy to maintain a currentPageIndex for **each** GET request/service we have as it would clutter the Fragment which hosts our list views. The `LoaderManager` structure worked neatly for us because we created a wrapper class that would simply take in the callback of the respective list view, and thus we had a single point to manage pagination regardless of data model type. That is, our Fragment's recyclerview onScroll listener looked like this:

```
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    ...
    mLoadHandler.handleNewItemLoading(firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
    ...
}
```

and mLoaderHandler is an instance of:

```
/**
 * Handles new content loading for ListView if the list has been scrolled to the end
 */
public class ListLoadMoreHandler {

    private static final int MAX_PAGES_TO_LOAD = 10; 
    private boolean mLoadingContent;
    private int mPageIndex = 0;
    private int mTotalItemCount;
    private final LoaderManager mLoaderManager;
    private final int mLoaderId;
    private final LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<?> mCallBack;

    public ListLoadMoreHandler(LoaderManager loaderManager,
                                  int loaderId,
                                  LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<?> callback) {
        mLoaderManager = loaderManager;
        mLoaderId = loaderId;
        mCallBack = callback;
    }

    /**
     * Trigger loading of new items when end of list view is reached
     * @param firstVisibleItem first visible item in list view
     * @param visibleItemCount visible items in list view
     * @param totalItemCount total items in list view
     */
    public void handleNewItemLoading(int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (totalItemCount == 0 || totalItemCount < RestClient.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_SIZE) {
            return;
        }

        int visibleTrigger = 2;
        if (mPageIndex < MAX_PAGES_TO_LOAD && !mLoadingContent &&
                (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleTrigger)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "restarting loader");
            mLoadingContent = true;
            mPageIndex++;
            mLoaderManager.restartLoader(mLoaderId, null, mCallBack);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Any suggestions on how to write a **scalable, retrofit-compliant** version of ListLoadMoreHandler?

Comment: Retrofit 2 introduces a nice way to handle pagination. It's currently in beta but fairly stable. Might be worth a look! See 16:34 and onwards in this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIAoQbAu3eA&t=16m34s

Comment: this looks like a job for generics. I would have a data type `Container<T>` that has `List<T> data` and `PagingInfo paging` and then define that `getComments` returns `Container<Comment>` (because as is, your service does not return a `List<Comment>`, unless you add a custom Gson deserializer)

Comment: Great ideas, @stkent and njzk2. I'll incorporate both suggestions and post my solution here